# Live Cookie Checker in js

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cookies

I'm working on a solution that checks the cookies in real time.

Once you have opened a link, a cookie is created. This cookie should be checked in real time and depending on the content, the corresponding text (send button) should be displayed.

The code works. Where I have the problem is with the IF sequence, which should be checked again and again without reloading the page.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function SetCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (3560*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires;
};

function getCookieValue(a) {
    var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
    return b ? b.pop() : '';    
};
</script>

<a href="https://webseite.ch" target="_blank" onClick="SetCookie(\klickonbutton','ja')"><img src="bilder/icon.png"  height="75"></a>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

if (getCookieValue("klickonbutton") == 'ja') {  
    document.write ('<input type="submit" value="Senden" id="senden">');
} else {
    document.write ('<p><b><font color="#FF0000">Error Message</b></font></p>');
    document.write ('<input type="submit" value="Senden" id="senden" disabled="disabled">');
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi domec0, welcome to StackOverflow! Please, would you be more descriptive on what your 'problem' is with the IF statement by perhaps describing what it is NOT doing or if it is generating any unwanted output? (seeing as you say the code works)

Comment: You can use `setInterval` to continuously run code on a timer again and again. But once you write the HTML to the page, you have to either remove it before writing again or you have to update the HTML you created if you want to avoid duplicating the elements on the screen. The code that checks for the cookie and displays content should be wrapped in a resusable function that `setInterval` will call.

Comment: Sorry! The IF query works.
The user will click on the link https://website.ch and then opens a new browser tab. At the same time a cookie is written (klickonbutton). Now the If query should check continuously if the cookie is set. currently he does this only when reloading the page. This reload of the page should not be necessary.

Comment: I've already tried setInterval. When I place the IF query in the setInterval, the page is completely deleted and only displays the button or error message.

Answer (score -1):

`document.write` deletes the entire HTML and adds the Html which you specify in the parameter. Instead what you should do is add the button and error div on the HTML and toggle the display of these based on the cookie value. Check out the sample code.

```
<a href="https://webseite.ch"  target="_blank" onClick="SetCookie('klickonbutton','ja')"><img src="bilder/icon.png"  height="75"></a>
<input type="submit" value="Senden" id="senden">
<p style="display: none" id="error"><b><font color="#FF0000">Error Message</b></font></p>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

  function SetCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (3560*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires;
    checkIsCookieAvailable();
  };

  function getCookieValue(a) {
    var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
    return b ? b.pop() : '';
  };

  function checkIsCookieAvailable() {
    const senden = document.querySelector('#senden');
    const error = document.querySelector('#error');
    setInterval(() => {
      if (getCookieValue("klickonbutton") == 'ja') {
        senden.style.display = 'block';
        senden.disabled = false;
        error.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        error.style.display = 'block';
        senden.disabled = true;
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Boolean Twen, and welcome to StackOverflow! While your code is a good solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You should add explanation and comments.